# how to plot a 2d image in 3d plot for calculating depth of object as z axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

[image]

I want to plot a 2D image in 3D map for calculating depth of object and for same I have made a code but that code is giving me an error for calculating distance z as depth.

error is `shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import  math
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


image2=cv2.imread('i1.jpg')
image2 = image2[:,:,1] # get the first channel
rows, cols = image2.shape
x, y= np.meshgrid(range(cols), range(rows)[::-1])

blurred = ndimage.gaussian_filter(image2,(5, 5))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax.imshow(image2, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax.elev= 5
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,image2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax.imshow(blurred, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')
ax.elev= 5
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,blurred)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you specify which line exactly pops up the error? Can you add the full error trace? Did you check the shapes of all arrays involved (x, y, z, blurred, image2)?   Also note that matplotlib only has limited 3D capabilities, drawing plots layer-by-layer.

Comment: the code giving error in line-   ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,image2)   X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z) and then ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape. i checked shape ,all x,y,z are 2d arrays.

Comment: Why are you giving 4 unnamed parameters to a function that only accepts 3. You can only give an x, y and a corresponding z to [`plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface)

Comment: i want to find out depth of pothole in image so i tried to draw pothole in 3d plot and then want to get value of max Z and min Z value from plot .

Comment: i checked without giving z argument its working .could you please tell me how can i get max Z and min Z value of pothole  drawn in  3d plot. it will be big help for me. thanks in advanced

Comment: You could try `idx = np.argmax(z)` and then `print(x[idx], y[idx])`? [argmax docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

Comment: this is not giving me max or min value from plotted image in 3d . could you please check attached image  above. I need max value of projected image not the array. 
 here print(x[idx], y[idx]) also giving a IndexError: index 46381 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 183.

Comment: Well, x, y and z need to have the same shape for this to work. `z` is not defined in the post. `z = z.reshape(x.shape)` could work.